# Query on MongoDB-Java Fetch Embedded node details

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 100 documents of customer data. Each document have 300 transactions in them. So in total there are 3000 transaction for 100 customers.

Now if I need to retrieve top 10 transactions done recently irrespective of any customers, how can I do this with MongoDB and Java?
Please

Example:

```
{
'customer':{
            'custId':111,
            ...
            ...,
            {
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t001',
                        'tname':'purchase',
                        'amt':'5000'
            },
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t002',
                        'tname':'credit',
                        'amt':'15000'
            },
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t001',
                        'tname':'debit',
                        'amt':'6500'
            }
            }
```

},
'customer':{
        'custId':112,
            ...
            ...
            {
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t011',
                        'tname':'purchase',
                        'amt':'51000'
            },
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t002',
                        'tname':'credit',
                        'amt':'15200'
            },
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t001',
                        'tname':'debit',
                        'amt':'6509'
            }
            }
}
'customer':{
        'custId':113,
            ...
            ...
            {
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t001',
                        'tname':'purchase',
                        'amt':'5900'
            },
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t3302',
                        'tname':'credit',
                        'amt':'18000'
            },
            'transactions':{
                        'tid':'t401',
                        'tname':'debit',
                        'amt':'5800'
            }
            }
}
...

}

Expected Result: 
Top 10 transactions details from 100 customers

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by top 10 transactions, is that most recent? is it largest `amt`

Comment: yes top 10  means recent transactions

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824397/mongodb-sort-by-subdocument-with-unknown-name. I wonder if its worth considering to restructure. 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for java code or just the query?
considering you want it irrespective of which customer, 
this should probably do? (if you do not wish to sort it, remove the sort block.

```
 db.emplog.find({},{"customer.transactions":1,"_id":0}).sort({"customer.transactions":-1}).limit(10)
```

Comment: But above limit(10) will apply on customer and not on the transaction node .Expected Result::We need to apply limit on transaction

Comment: oops! that's right. let me get back. Probably need to unwind it